# List of Maps returns undefined in DynamoDB query

Tags: node.js, rest, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I am querying a DynamoDB. It has an attribute called 'Multiple Units' with the following structure: List [ Map { Map { S }, S }, ... ]

I test a lambda locally:

```
module.exports.getByAddress = async (event) => {
  const params = {
    TableName: process.env.tableName,
    Key: { 
      Address: event.pathParameters.address
    }
  };
  var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({apiVersion: '2012-08-10'});
  docClient.get(params).promise().then(
    returnResult => console.log(returnResult)
  )
}
```

This is the output:

```
Item: {
...
license: '',
Coordinates: { lng: '-71.075985', lat: '42.346096' },
'Multiple Units': [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
...
}
```

When I attempt to console.log Multiple Units list specifically, I get undefined.
In reading about DynamoDB get/getItem, I am guessing it has to do with async but I cannot configure a change that will result in correct output.

Comment: Can you show the code where you output the Multiple Units list?  It'll be easier for people to help you if you show the code and it's output.

Comment: I am just console.logging in .then(). Instead of return, I run: console.log(returnResult['Multiple Units']), the output of which is: 'undefined'. I expect an array.

Comment: Thats helpful, I posted an answer below.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment, you mention that you're getting `undefined` when you execute `console.log(returnResult['Multiple Units'])`.

Take a closer look at what `console.log(returnResult)` is printing:

```
Item: {
   ...
   license: '',
   Coordinates: { lng: '-71.075985', lat: '42.346096' },
   'Multiple Units': [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
...
}
```

Notice that it's printing a `map` with the key of `Item`.  Therefore, to get at your data, try to `console.log(returnResult.Item['Multiple Units'])`

You can check out the [DynamoDB SDK API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html#get-property) for more info regarding the result of a `get` call.

Comment: Hi @Seth, I have noticed that you are expert on Dynamodb, Could please help me this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71391184/invalid-updateexpression-an-expression-attribute-value-used-in-expression-is-no